how to show function/method parameter hints in Kdevelop, C++?
The title is completely expressive:
how to show function/method parameter hints in Kdevelop, C++?
UPDATE
My system specifications:

Ubuntu 22.04
KDevelop version: 5.7.211203 (21.12.3)

